# The specified module 'Az' with version '8.0.0' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory

Tags: azure-powershell, powershell-az-module

I have a PS script as a YAML task to install Az module. On deployment, I see this error:

> The specified module 'Az' with version '8.0.0' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory.

Here is the script:

```
Install-Module Az -RequiredVersion 8.0.0 -Scope CurrentUser -Force -AllowClobber
Import-Module Az -RequiredVersion 8.0.0 -Force
```

What am I missing?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After upgrading the version to 9.0.1, it worked fine!